# How to customize the JavaScript prompt?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the JavaScript prompt for entering text that will be enclosed between tags e.g

[url]http://www.yahoo.com[/url]

The problem is that the prompt always appear in the top left corner of the browser.

How do I position such that it only display the prompt around the text area where the text will be entered?

And also how do I customize the JavaScript prompt so that it look more user friendly?

Comment: You mean you have JS popping up a floating text box/input field? If it's in the topleft corner, you're using the wrong positioning logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can't customize that (if you are refering at prompt()). You need to create a pop up window and customize its insides.

Answer (score 1):

You can't position the JavaScript prompt box, and you'll find it varies between different browsers.

Although you didn't explicitly ask, may I suggest either creating your own prompt (as simple as making a div with an input and positioning absolutely, and setting the display CSS property correctly to "pop" it up and close it, or (and this is what I would do) use something like jQueryUI or a similar alternative that will do what you want.

One final bonus: just insert the [url][/url] tags with a placeholder domain or message imbeteen, and automatically highlight it and give it focus, so that when they start typing it will appear there, inline.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an accepted way:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          console.log("deleted")
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          console.log("cancelled")
        }
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
 
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```