# Javascript prompt

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to customize `javascript prompt` box?

I want to make my `prompt` to accept only numeric input... (I want to `bind` the `keyup event` - to be specific)

Is it possible?

Comment: "Is it possible"... No. You can use one of the thousands of existing lightbox scripts to create your own version though. Or validate the input once the user has entered it and then pop up another prompt if it wasn't acceptable.

Comment: As an alternative, you could try [jQuery UI dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form).

Comment: Just, just, just... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+customize+prompt

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the JavaScript prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193333/how-to-customize-the-javascript-prompt)

Comment: Thanks for the response people :).. I wanted to get it working asap for the demo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot, but you may want to research Javascript modal windows - they may be what you are looking for. Or you can do something like this:

```
do {
  number = parseInt(prompt('Please enter a number'))
}
while (isNaN(number))
```

Comment: Although technically this may work, I would not suggest this. At least... I hope my own current browser would kill scripts on a page that tries this kind of folly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with the default javascript prompt. But you could use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use one of many modal dialog's http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/#.UCotfJ0gerg

You can put in anything inside those forms and bind any kind of callback functions.

But you can not definitely style standard browser's prompt or alert box.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const first = Number(prompt("1st number"))
const second = Number(prompt("2nd number"))

function sum() {
  if (isNaN(first + second)) {
    alert("NaN")
  } else {
    alert(first + second)
  }
}
sum();
```